# ember adapter url - find by id pattern - nested api resources

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember.js-2

I've got an api with specific url structure. How do I pass the ID to the url string using an adapter or something? There's only one model, `patient` but I need to query each of these items plus more. I've seen where you can place the id at the end of the url, but I'm not sure how to build an additional string to a find query. Thanks!

GET: `/api/v1/me/patients/{id}`

GET: `/api/v1/me/patients/{patient_id}/public_number`

This is what the model has in it:

```
/models/patient.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
    public_number:  DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[You can override `buildUrl` on your adapter.](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_buildURL)

Comment: Well you can just call `this._super(...arguments);` and then modify the URL as needed. What example do you need there?

Comment: Would you query it like this? `this.store.queryRecord('patient', 100157, 'public_number')`

Comment: Found this useful resource. http://blog.ksol.fr/ember-data-working-with-nested-api-resources/